# tacking a row onto the bottom of a dataframe

Tags: pandas, append, concatenation

I have two data frames:

DF1 = 14 rows x 49 columns (US States)

DF2 = 1 row x 49 columns (US states)

I'm trying to add DF2 on to the bottom of DF1 to create: 15 rows x 49 columns

I've tried append() and concat() and it keeps returning a dataframe which is: 15 rows x 98 columns all of which are NaN except for row 15 , columns 50:98. ??

```
result = census_data.append(total_guns_2007)
```

Comment: Hey Alan - can You provide the structuree of that dataframes? - those are probably have different columns.

Comment: @PiotrŻak yes there was a slight discrepancy in the column names - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because the columns are different.

Try this -

```
total_guns_2007.columns = census_data.columns.values #this will make the column name same.
result = census_data.append(total_guns_2007)
```